# Scroll message history in echo area

Tags: echo-area, message

I want to use commands/keybindings to quickly view and scroll recent messages in the echo area, without visiting the *Messages* buffer. For example, suppose I received messages:

```
Time is 15:00:01
Time is 15:00:03
Time is 15:00:04
```

- echo area displays: `Time is 15:00:04`
- press key (eg. `M-p`)
- echo area displays: `Time is 15:00:03`
- press key (eg. `M-n`)
- echo area displays: `Time is 15:00:04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rudimentary attempt at such a thing,

```lisp
(defun my:peek-messages (clear)
  (interactive "P")
  (when (or (not (bound-and-true-p my:messages-stack)) clear)
    (setq
      my:messages-stack
      (butlast (split-string
        (with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
          (buffer-string)) "\n"))))
  (let ((message-log-max nil))
    (message (car (last my:messages-stack))))
  (setq my:messages-stack (butlast my:messages-stack)))
```

Bind this to `M-p` and it does what you want.  Now, there is a caveat. To make the function start displaying from the last message again, you have to `C-u M-p`. I. e., set the prefix argument.

Comment: I should be able to implement `M-n` having seen this. Nice use of `(message-log-max nil)` to stop messages being duplicated in the *Messages* buffer